# 3D features (Polyline, Polygon) intersection library

Tags: python, postgis, features, 3d, intersection

For my research I am looking for a (python) library to get the intersection of some 3D features. The features can be Polygons or Polylines. Mostly I need to intersect a plane with my features and get the result.
After some search I came to CGAL, but CGAL build is not successful because of some missing stuff (Eigen) and since I am not very linux, cmake and make literate, I am searching for something else.
(PostGIS  is also OK, but the ST_Intersection seems to work only in 2D).

Comment: For 3D support you need PostGIS 2.  You say you are not very Linux literate - do you have access to Windows? If so I highly recommend this site for the pre-compiled Windows GDAL binaries: http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/.

Comment: My PostGIS version is 2.0.1 but still the ST_Intersection returns "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY". For example for this intersection I assume it should the point at (1,1,0), but doesn't: SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection('LINESTRING Z(1 1 -1, 1 1 1)'::geometry, 'POLYGON Z (( 0 0 0, 2 0 0, 2 2 0, 0 2 0, 0 0 0))'::geometry));

Comment: And the same example returns "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY" using GDAL/OGR